# Tenant does not have a SPO license. With Onedrive Service e O365 family license

Tags: python, java, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Good morning

I'm a new user on stack overflow and I know that the problem is not new but I do not found a solution.

I use python MSAL library to call the ms graph API.

I have a tenant with O365 family license and I verified that the tenant in Azure AAD is the same for my O365 license

The python code is OK to get info on my profile but i have the error with "application" method:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c9445de4-23db-4596-a1d3-7760dce5a3a6/drive/root

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Tenant does not have a SPO license.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-02-17T10:34:31",
      "request-id": "a0f521e4-d673-4856-b248-ff480a248ab9",
      "client-request-id": "a0f521e4-d673-4856-b248-ff480a248ab9"
    }
  }
}
```

and with the "delegate" methode
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Tenant does not have a SPO license.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-02-17T11:09:33",
      "request-id": "24b27408-6dfe-4612-84d9-b5c184225cdc",
      "client-request-id": "24b27408-6dfe-4612-84d9-b5c184225cdc"
    }
  }
}
```

I have the same problem with Java:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Drive;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionPage;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String tenant = "<my tenant>";
        String clientId = "<my client>";
        String clientSecret = "<my secret>";
        
        List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

        try {
            final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId(tenant)
            .build();

            final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);

            final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();

            final UserCollectionPage me = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();

            System.out.println(me.getCurrentPage().get(0).id);

            final Drive result = graphClient
                .users(me.getCurrentPage().get(0).id)
                .drive()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();

            System.out.println("Found Drive " + result.id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
            
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential - Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
c9445de4-23db-4596-a1d3-7760dce5a3a6
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential - Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409Graph service exception Error code: BadRequest
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409Error message: Tenant does not have a SPO license.
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c9445de4-23db-4596-a1d3-7760dce5a3a6/drive
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.14.0
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409400 : Bad Request
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409[...]
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 409[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
Feb 18, 2022 3:56:47 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: Tenant does not have a SPO license.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c9445de4-23db-4596-a1d3-7760dce5a3a6/drive
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.14.0


400 : Bad Request
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
```

Thanks for help

Silvano

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in graph explorer ,if no? ,could you please try first in graph explorer and if you are getting the same error ,please check your access token on https://jwt.ms/ and cross-verify your required permissions , please follow the docs to check permission - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , feel free to react out to us if you have any query?

Thanks.

Comment: tried this in graph explorer and it is Ok. I tested also with java and I have the same error, see my modified post.

Comment: Hi @SilvanoMontanari , Have you login to graph explorer before testing the URI ? could you please copy the access token and retry the same operation in postman as well.  please check access token on https://jwt.ms/ and provide the screenshot of access token.